# Kubernetes can't access gitlab registry with access token

Tags: docker, kubernetes, gitlab

I'm deploying my app hosted on Gitlab registry on Kubernetes.

From Gitlab, I generated an access token and created a secret

```
kubectl create secret docker-registry gitlab-registry \
 --docker-server=registry.gitlab.com \
 --docker-username=kosted \
 --docker-password=HERE-MY-SECRET \
 --docker-email=HERE-MY-MAIL
```

They are all valid.
But when I deploy my app, I got this error :

```
Warning  Failed     17s (x2 over 34s)  kubelet, gke-gara-cluster-default-pool-affe594e-hslk  Failed to pull image "registry.gitlab.com/gara-project/back-end-micro-services/mebooks:latest": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: Get https://registry.gitlab.com/v2/gara-project/back-end-micro-services/mebooks/manifests/latest: denied: access forbidden
  Warning  Failed     17s (x2 over 34s)  kubelet, gke-gara-cluster-default-pool-affe594e-hslk  Error: ErrImagePull
  Normal   BackOff    5s (x3 over 33s)   kubelet, gke-gara-cluster-default-pool-affe594e-hslk  Back-off pulling image "registry.gitlab.com/gara-project/back-end-micro-services/mebooks:latest"
  Warning  Failed     5s (x3 over 33s)   kubelet, gke-gara-cluster-default-pool-affe594e-hslk  Error: ImagePullBackOff
```

I know that everything works fine, because when I change the access token by my password, kubernetes can access the registry and download the docker image, but I don't want to pu in clear my password.

Please, how could I do ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you able to do docker login and docker pull using the token?Did you generate a deploy token?

Comment: yes, i'm able to do docker login. I just find the solution. The docker login value is not my login my email. I don't know why they ask for login if we have to put email value for this property